# How to create a View component with generic properties in SwiftUI?

Tags: generics, swiftui, iosdeployment

folks. I am new in ios developmet. Now I am trying to develop a dropdown by using the Picker and my goal is to make it as much as possible generic. How can I pass a generic values to my picker's View properties instead of using the `SelectMenuItem` struct?
Here is my Picker View Component:

```
struct SelectMenuItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var value: String
}

struct SelectionMenuView: View {
    var title: String
    var menuItems: [SelectMenuItem]
    
    @Binding var selectedOption: SelectMenuItem
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(title, selection: $selectedOption) {
            Text("Placeholder")
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
            ForEach(menuItems, id: \.self){ menuItem in
                Text(menuItem.value)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is updating your example of `SelectMenuItem`. On top of `Hashable` and `Identifiable` we will conform to `View`:

```swift
struct SelectMenuItem: Identifiable, Hashable, View {
    var id: UUID
    var value: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
    }
}
```

Now, every `SelectMenuItem` is also a view because it conforms to the `View` protocol.

Since you want a placeholder in your picker, and the picker might start without a selected value, we should make the `selectedOption` optional. This means it can start as nil (no value). If you are passing this value in from a previous screen, or another area in the app, it would be worth making this a `Binding` otherwise, having the `@State` on this view isn't bad - it all depends:

```swift
@Binding var selectedOption: MenuItem?
```

For the `SelectionMenuView`, we use a generic type `MenuItem`. This generic type is flexible, but we need to tell Swift that it should be something that can be identified, something that is hashable (can be uniquely represented), and is a view:

```swift
struct SelectionMenuView<MenuItem: Identifiable & Hashable & View>: View
```

In the body of `SelectionMenuView`, we use a `ForEach` to loop through all the menu items. Each menu item is displayed, and we use tag to make sure each one is uniquely identifiable:

```swift
Picker(title, selection: $selectedOption) {
    Text("Placeholder")
        .tag(nil as MenuItem?)
    
    ForEach(menuItems) { menuItem in
        menuItem
            .tag(menuItem as MenuItem?)
    }
}
.tint(.red)
```

---

Finally, if you are passing this selectedOption from another area in the app, you can set it up like so:

```swift
struct SelectionParentView: View {
    @State private var selectedMenuItem: SelectMenuItem?
    let menuItems = [
        SelectMenuItem(id: UUID(), value: "Option 1"),
        SelectMenuItem(id: UUID(), value: "Option 2")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        SelectionMenuView(title: "Choose an Option", menuItems: menuItems, selectedOption: $selectedMenuItem)
    }
}
```